# No se puede insertar el valor NULL en la columna. La columna no admite valores NULL. Error de INSERT

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-core

Tengo una app donde un usuario puede crear varias cuentas. Al intentar insertar una cuenta, me manda un error donde me pide más campos que son obligatorios de la tabla usuarios, como si tratara de insertar un usuario nuevo tambien, donde solo se requiere asignarle el id del usuario a la cuenta e insetar solo la cuenta.

[Repo de GitHub](https://github.com/AlejandroArelis/Accounts.git)

Primero hay que que crear las migraciones.

**Estructura para crear un usuario con [POST] /api/user**

```
{
  "name": "Prueba"
}
```

**Obtener un usuario para empezar a crear cuentas [GET] /api/user**

```
[
  {
    "id": "1686430c-4321-41e0-9fe4-08da99ae0e7a",
    "name": "Usuario ejemplo",
    "accounts": null
  }
]
```

**Esta es la estructura que requiere el post en Swagger utilizando DTOs
[POST] /api/account/user**

```
{
  "name": "Cuenta ejemplo",
  "value": 12345,
  "user": {
    "id": "1686430c-4321-41e0-9fe4-08da99ae0e7a"
  }
}
```

**Error que me da al ejecutar la consulta**
No se puede insertar el valor NULL en la columna 'Name', tabla 'gastos2.dbo.Users'. La columna no admite valores NULL. Error de INSERT.

**Estas son las entidades**

```
public class User
{
  [Key]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}
 
public class Account
{
  [Key]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [DefaultValue (0)]
  public decimal Value { get; set; }
  [Required]
  [ForeignKey("user")]
  public User User { get; set; }
}
```

**Estos son los DTOs**

```
public class GetUserByIdDTO
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "El id del usuario es obligatorio")]
  public Guid Id { get; set; } 
}
 
public class InsertAccountDTO
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre de la cuenta es obligatoria")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "El cantidad de dinero en la cuenta es obligatoria")]
  public decimal Value { get; set; }
  public GetUserByIdDTO User { get; set; }
}
```

**Estos son los perfiles de AutoMapper que tengo hasta ahora**

```
public AutoMapperProfiles()
{
  // Users
  CreateMap<GetByIdDTO, User>();
 
  // Accounts
  CreateMap<InsertDTO, Account>();
}
```

**Este es el post para insertar una cuenta**

```
[HttpPost("user")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] InsertAccountDTO account)
{
  bool exists = await context.Users.AnyAsync(x => x.Id == account.User.Id);
 
  if (exists)
  {
      exists = await context.Accounts.AnyAsync(x => x.Name == account.Name);
 
      if(!exists)
      {
          Account newAccount = mapper.Map<Account>(account);
 
          context.Add(newAccount);
          await context.SaveChangesAsync();
          return Ok(newAccount);
      }
 
      return BadRequest($"La cuenta {account.Name} ya existe");
  }
 
  return BadRequest($"El usuario {account.User.Id} no existe");
}
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

¿Como podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu problema está en que cuando le envía la account va con un user dentro, y al insertar el EF quiere insertar ambos.

Pero todo se origina porque tu modelo (al parecer está mal seteado) le falta una referencia a la tabla usuario, pienso que debería ser asi:

```
public class Account
{
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre de la cuenta es obligatoria")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El cantidad de dinero en la cuenta es obligatoria")]
        [DefaultValue (0)]
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El propietario (usuario) de la cuenta es obligatorio")]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; } //ESTO TE FALTA

        [IgnoreDataMember] // ESTE Decorador para que no lo muestre en el swagger
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
  public class InsertDTO
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El nombre de la cuenta es obligatoria")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El cantidad de dinero en la cuenta es obligatoria")]
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El usuario de la cuenta es obligatorio")]
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

Tú le colocaste [ForeignKey("user")] al objeto User, cuando debería ir en una propiedad del mismo tipo del PK de la tabla User.

*Nota: Cuando pones Id en una tabla, y en otra pones TablaId, automáticamente la convierte el FK y no es necesario colocar el decorador*

*Nota2: Recuerda que deberás reconstruir la BD, para esto puedes usar Database.EnsureCreated(); en el constructor del dbcontext

*Nota3: Como observación personal, Yo he hecho muchas API's y muchos desarrollos en .net y nunca he necesitado ocupar clases DTO y Automapper, y menos si la BD se hace por Code First. Mira que tu necesitas 2 clases y con este modo tienes 5, imagina si sigue creciendo.